# What design pattern should I use to avoid dummy code here?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a base class -

```
class content
{

private:
  int m_data;

public:

  int getdbhandle() { return m_sql_db; }

  void setData(int data) { m_data = data; }

  virtual int getterrestrialServices { qDebug()"This is a dummy interface"; }

};


class telecontent: public content
{

   virtual int getterrestrialServices { qDebug()" Real implementation here"; }

};
```

Now, the class content is instantiated as telecontent, when the product type is tele.
However, when the product type is generic - the dummy interface prints keep coming.
How can I avoid so? Is there any design pattern that forces the base class not to implement the dummy function? I want an efficient way so that only derived class has method. I don't want the base class to have that method. But, I can't modify the caller - code- so that the method is not called. I want the best way to strategically design such that the dummy interface can be avoided.

Comment: Why don't you make it pure virtual?

Comment: Don't forget virtual destructor.

Comment: You can use a *pure virtual function* like this: `virtual int getterrestrialServices() = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

> is there any design pattern that forces the base class not to
>   implement the dummy function?

Pure virtual allows this:

```
class content
{

private:
  int m_data;

public:
  virtual ~content() { }
  int getdbhandle() { return m_sql_db; }

  void setData(int data) { m_data = data; }

  virtual int getterrestrialServices() = 0; // pure virtual

};
```

This means no one can create instances of content (will cause a compiler error), and so when some one inherits from content they must provide an implementation of getterrestrialServices() (else again, they'll get a compiler error).

Comment: But this method getterrestrialServices makes sense only in one derived class, and other derived class doesn't need this at all. However, I can only access derived class using the base class type. It's like Base *telecontentPtr = new telecontent();

Comment: This is a different problem to what your question asks, pure virtual does what you asked here. The problem you state in the comment is a broken design, only workaround is to use dynamic_cast to get the one specific derived type that does implement this method.

Comment: @user3629119 - Then you have a bad design.  Why are you calling a highly specialized function `getrestrialServices` in a generic part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pure virtual like so:

```
virtual int getterrestrialServices() = 0;
```

It will force every class the inherits content to implement it and you wont be able to create a content class, only classes the inherit from it so you wont have the dummy prints.